# How to create a function that takes a list of arguments and returns a function that applies arguments to another function

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, function-composition

This sounds like a weird question but bear with me.
I want to create a function that takes a list of arguments, and returns a function that applies those arguments to another function. I can get this to work with a set length of arguments using tuples or pattern matching like so:

```
applyAll (x, y, z) = ($ z) . ($ y) . ($ x)

applyAll [x, y, z] = ($ z) . ($ y) . ($ x)
```

Those both compile and function as expected.

I noticed that those look very recursive and wanted to make a version that takes any length of arguments. These are my attempts at that:

```
applyAll []     = id
applyAll (x:xs) = applyAll xs . ($ x)

applyAll []     = id
applyAll (x:xs) = ($ x) . applyAll xs
```

This does not work however. I get this error:

```
num.hs:121:5: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b1 ~ a2 -> b1
      Expected type: [a2] -> b1 -> c
        Actual type: [a2] -> (a2 -> b1) -> c
```

I don't quite understand this error, but seeing as the original function worked, and was not recursive I think it has something to do with the recursion.

Maybe something to do with the order of operations with the function?
This is how I imagine the function looks when executed with three variables:

```
applyAll [x, y, z] = ($ x) . (($ y) . (($ z) . (id)))
```

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is that you create an infinite type here, since the list can be arbitrary long.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is there a way to create this function with an arbitrarily long list?

Comment: @ByceTheGrand: what would the type of that function be?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good point. Maybe a way to return a list of ($ x) functions and map them all to one function with a separate function?

Comment: `applyAll (x, y, z) = ($ z) . ($ y) . ($ x)` Look at the type of `applyAll`. (It's `(a1, a2, a3) -> (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> c) -> c`). What type do you want the arbitrary list version to have?

Comment: For the original idea, I can't thing of one. For the one I mentioned in the comments I am thinking maybe like: [a] -> [b -> a] where each (b -> a) is essentially a ($ x) function. Then fold those with a function?

Comment: Handling functions of "unknown arity" can not be easily done in Haskell, like "variadic functions". There might be some type-tricks which can make this work, like it was done for `printf`, possibly exploiting (overlapping) typeclasses and/or type families. If the input is an HList it could also be done. There are quite advanced techniques, though.

Comment: Is there more context to this problem? This seems like it could be an XY problem to me.

Comment: You could make an `apply`-like function with template haskell (i.e. metaprogramming) or dependent types, but this is fairly complex especially if you're a beginner.